# Десериализация Json строки

Tags: c#, json

Получаю извне вот такую json строку:

```
[
    {"spray": "250.00","ip": "202.214.237.72"}, //единственная отличающаяся строка
    {"access": "444","sum": "100.00","date": "13.07.2020 19:28:49","pass": "0"},
    {"access": "444","sum": "50.00","date": "13.07.2020 19:21:00","pass": "1"},
    { /*похожий формат строки, до конца документа json */ }
]
```

Создал 2 класса

```
    public class Product    {
        public string spray { get; set; } 
        public string ip { get; set; } 
        public string access { get; set; } 
        public string sum { get; set; } 
        public string date { get; set; } 
        public string pass { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Shop    {
        public List<Product> Product { get; set; } 

    }
```

Десериализация, заполняю как массив.

```
Shop shop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shop>(JsonString);
```

Как извлечь данные из shop и вывести все в виде таблицы на форму?

Comment: 1. Если у вас разные объекты в JSON, то наверно и классы должны быть разные? Зачем пихать все в одно место. 2. Где вы увидели коллекцию, которая содержит в себе еще коллекцию под названием `Product` в своем JSON? Я лично вижу просто массив объектов, не более. Так может не `List<Shop>>`, а `Product[]`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Совершенно верно `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(JsonString);` и конечно же классы должны быть разные. Только, как сказать, что бы в первый класс попадал только первый объект, а во второй все остальные кроме первого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Проблема со структурой

Давайте визуализируем то, что вы получаете:

[image: JSON Struct]

Как видите, тут просто массив объектов. Почему тогда вы пытаетесь это засунуть в `List<Product> Product`, да который еще и в `List<Shop>`? По вашему тогда JSON должен выглядеть так:

[image: JSON struct error]

Похоже это на то, что отдает вам сервер или кто там? Я думаю, что нет. По этому, `List<Shop>` можно смело заменять на `Product[]`, удаляя полностью класс `Shop`.

### Неверный тип данных

Хорошо, со структурой разобрались, давайте теперь поговорим о другом. Почему вы все засовываете в `string`? Да, я понимаю, это проще и может понятней, но ведь это очень неудобно! Вот вам надо сравнить значение `sum` и взять те объекты, которые выше скажем 20, как будете это делать с типом `string`? Правильно, вы будете пытаться перегнать это в нужный тип и уже потом проверять. Так почему не сделать так, чтобы в классе был сразу нужный нам тип?

Тут будет пару подводных камней, ибо по умолчанию десериализатор плохо понимает некоторые типы, например за ip в c# отвечает `IPAddress` и для того, чтобы в него преобразовать входную строку надо будет сделать отдельный конвертор, например такой:

```
class IPAddressConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(IPAddress);
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => IPAddress.Parse((string)reader.Value);
}
```

Также проблема будет и с датой, ибо она у вас имеет не стандартный формат и этот формат вам тоже надо будет задать при помощи конвертора, он простой:

```
class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format) => DateTimeFormat = format;
}
```

### Данные несколько классов в одном

Далее, почему у вас все в одном месте? Ведь вам отдают два совершенно разных объекта, один отвечающий за ip, а другой за доступ наверно? Может стоит их разделить?
Сделать это можно при помощи конвертера и некого абстрактного класса или интерфейса.

1. Сделаем пустой интерфейс, который будет просто некой меткой для нужных нам классов:

   ```
   public interface IJsonData { }
   ```
2. Разделим данные на несколько классов, где каждый класс наследуется от интерфейса и реализует только то, что ему необходимо:

   ```
   public class IpData : IJsonData
   {
       public IpData(double spray, IPAddress ip)
           => (Spray, Ip) = (spray, ip);

       public double Spray { get; }

       [JsonConverter(typeof(IPAddressConverter))]
       public IPAddress Ip { get; }
   }

   public class AccessData : IJsonData
   {
       public AccessData(int access, double sum, DateTimeOffset date, int pass)
           => (Access, Sum, Date, Pass) = (access, sum, date, pass);

       public int Access { get; }
       public double Sum { get; }

       [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "dd.MM.yyyy HH':'mm':'ss")]
       public DateTimeOffset Date { get; }
       public int Pass { get; }
   }
   ```

   Тут заодно и применим конверторы для типов и будем использовать сразу нужные нам типы с удобными именами.
3. Сделаем конвертор, который будет брать объект, искать например `ip` и если он есть, то все преобразовывать в тип `IpData`, иначе в `AccessData`:

   ```
   public class JsonDataConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
           => objectType == typeof(IJsonData);
       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
           => throw new InvalidOperationException("Use default serialization.");

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
           return jsonObject["ip"] != null ? jsonObject.ToObject<IpData>() : (IJsonData) jsonObject.ToObject<AccessData>();
       }
   }
   ```

   Тут собственно стандартный конвертор, который позволяет применить его только тогда, когда входящий тип равен нашему интерфейсу, обратной конвертации нету. Сама конвертация, как я уже описывал выше, работает так, что мы ищем `ip`, если он не `NULL`, то преобразуем в `IpData`, иначе в `AccessData`.
4. Осталось нам десериализовать, добавив 2-м параметром конвертор:

   ```
   var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IJsonData[]>(jsonString, new JsonDataConverter());
   ```

### Результат

Запустив проект, мы можем увидеть, что будет массив из 3-х объектов, где первый отвечает за Ip:

[image: Result]

Имея это, мы можем делать уже дальше что хотим, например как вы просили вывести данные (я выведу в консоль):

```
foreach (var item in json)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case IpData ipData:
            Console.WriteLine($"Ip данные: {ipData.Ip} | {ipData.Spray}");
            break;
        case AccessData accesData:
            Console.WriteLine($"Access данные: {accesData.Date} | {accesData.Sum}");
            break;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Ip данные: 202.214.237.72 | 250
Access данные: 13.07.2020 19:28:49 +03:00 | 100
Access данные: 13.07.2020 19:21:00 +03:00 | 50
```

Собственно вот и все решение задачи. Удачи в изучении!
Глянуть весь пример можно [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3OT5uQ)

Comment: Замечательное решение @EvgeniyZ. Просидел всю ночь в дебаге пытаясь осознать, что происходит и как это работает. И когда под утро не смог получить длинну массива json - пошел спать. Сервер без авторизации отдает строку `{"access":"denied"}` но теперь это не сложно правильно обработать. В pass иногда встречаются строки, я просто оставил это в стрингах. Pass это не password это скорее всего passed, а access это видимо какие то права доступа.

Comment: @RootShell Ну с типами смотрите сами, я вам лишь показал пример как это может выглядеть и дал совет, что нужно использовать правильные типы, не более. Дальше уж сами смотрите что у вас там приходит от сервера)

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант.

Создадим следующие классы:

```
public class Data
{
    public string spray { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string access { get; set; }
    public string sum { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
}
```

Используем следующий код:

```
Data data = null;
var products = new List<Product>();

var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
bool isFirst = true;

using (var textReader = new StreamReader("test.json"))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
{
    while (jsonReader.Read())
    {
        if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                data = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(jsonReader);
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var product = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product>(jsonReader);
                products.Add(product);
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(data.spray + "   " + data.ip);

foreach (var p in products)
    Console.WriteLine(p.access + " " + p.sum + " " + p.date + " " + p.pass);
```

Логика такова. В json имеется массив объектов. Объекты заключены в фигурные скобки. Все объекты плоские, поэтому каждый из них начинается с открывающей скобки `{` и внутри нет вложенных скобок. Этот факт и используем.

Когда `jsonReader` встречает токен `JsonToken.StartObject` (это и есть `{`), мы десериализуем объект. Используем булев флаг `isFirst` для определения первой строки. Из неё заполняем первый класс. Остальные строки десериализуем в другой класс и добавляем в коллекцию.

---

Работа с потоковыми читателями, наподобие JsonReader, XmlReader и т. п., обычно считается сложной. На мой взгляд, незаслуженно. Если понимать устройство форматов данных (json/xml/csv etc), то их использование элементарно.